# Where to place a variable legend in a math thesis?

Tags: thesis, mathematics

In a math thesis, where do I place a variable legend, i.e. a list that indicates the "type" of each variable used, e.g.

- x, y, z denote real numbers
- s, t denote sets of numbers
- f, g denote functions

Comment: First, I don't think that's called a legend.  Second, one often has a notation section at the beginning.  Have you tried looking at other papers or theses?

Comment: @Kimball: What is it called then? Could you give me a link to a thesis that has such a legend (or whatever it's called)?

Comment: Hmm, may I ask for which reason you would like to include such a list? I know of a few articles (most of them are several decades old) where such a list is given (though in plain text rather than in list form), but in my experience this is done rarely nowadays (at least in pure maths) . Consistent nomenclature for variables is obviously a good thing, but for which reason would you like to explicitly mention it in a list, given that every variable that occurs has to be introduced at the place where it is used anyway?

Comment: @JochenGlueck: Just seems good form to me, and makes for an easier read. Just like an index or a glossary of symbols are redundant, but make reading much easier.

Comment: @EvanAad: Thanks for your reply! I completely agree that an index and a glossary of symbols are extremely important - but not due to a matter of form: the main point about mathematical notions and universally (throughout the text) used symbols is that they are defined at one point, and then used throughout the text. [...]

Comment: [...] So assume that you, as a reader, want to look up a theorem on page 86, and the theorem contains the sentence "Let $f,g \in L^{2,3}([0,1])$; then $f\cdot g$ is a mumbo jumbo foo." If you don't know what the notation $L^{2,3}$ means you have to look it up, and if you don't know that it is defined on page 34, a glossary of symbols is extremely useful. [...]

Comment: [...] Similarly, if you don't know what a "mumbo jumbo foo" is, the index is your best friend. On the other hand, there is no need at all in this example to look up how the variables $f$ and $g$ are typically used in the thesis, since they are actually quantified directly in the theorem. That's why I think that an index and a glossary are very useful, while a list with the typical meaning of variables is not.

Comment: @EvanAad I've usually seen it called a "List of Symbols", but like others I'm not convinced of its usefulness for the reader.

Comment: Check with the office that handles dissertations/theses.  Many universities have very specifc requirements for how you format the document.

Comment: Ask someone in your department?

Comment: I would call it a table of notation or something similar. It can go in an appendix or at the beginning of the thesis or anywhere else where you think it makes sense to put such a table (say, at the end of each chapter to summarize the notation used in that chapter). There is no standard place where it should go. Such tables are also not very common, but I have used them in some of my longer papers and find them quite useful. I’d recommend including one, but with more of a focus on the meaning of specific symbols rather than generic classes of symbols that denote real numbers, variables etc.

Comment: @DanRomik: Thanks. Do you know why my question was closed?

Comment: @EvanAad regarding your edit, the question you link is eight years and nine months old. Surely you can appreciate that the userbase of this site is not exactly the same as it was almost nine years ago, and hence you cannot possibly expect the level of consistency that you request.

Comment: @Wetenschaap: The point is, that question has evidently been very useful to many people, and it is hard to imagine any other stackexchange forum that would be more suitable for that question than the present one. Therefore, even if it were asked today, there would be no reason to close it, just like there is no reason to close my question, despite it concerning a more niche subject matter than a glossary.

Comment: The text in your edit would be better placed as a [meta question](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com). That is the place to discuss and resolve such disputes.

Comment: @EvanAad no, I wasn’t involved in the closing, but think it’s a reasonable decision as your question is only of interest to mathematicians.

Answer (score 4):

A commentator knows such a list as "List of Symbols", other names are "Mathematical notation", "Notational conventions", "Mathematical symbols", and permutations thereof. (Note that this is sometimes not a list but a text describing the notation.)

I just checked a few textbooks and found placement right before and after the table of contents, and as the first appendix. While I would prefer putting it right before the main text, it's really up to you.

Comment: I'm under the impression that "mathematical notation", "notational conventions", and so on, typically refer to the definition of symbols that have a fixed meaning *throughout the text*, whereas the OP refers to notational convention for *variables*.

Comment: I can't see why that wouldn't be a notational convention? Your comment even includes the term.

Comment: Oops, you're right, of course; I'm not quite sure what I was thinking... But I guess what I actually intended to say is: In a comment the OP suggests that they might list definitions of symbols in a glossary of symbols - so, given the question, I assume that they would like to list notational conventions for variables in a different list. But I think you're right that "notational convention" would probably be an accurate description of this second list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know why my question was closed?